# malware or Google Drive not working due to batch file being opened by text editor by default

Tags: windows-7, security, batch, google-drive

I'm seeing some suspicious behavior on startup, and am wondering if I should be concerned. What's happening is `C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpevpnra\run.bat` is being opened in `Notepad++`.

I'm assuming the reason for this is because some application (malicious or not) is trying to run it, but I have `.bat` files set to open with a text editor by default.

The following is the batch's contents:

```
%~dp0googledrivesync.exe --waitforrestartsignal="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe"

   :Repeat

   del %~dp0googledrivesync.exe

   if exist %dp0googledrivesync.exe goto Repeat

   rmdir %~dp0 /s /q
```

I don't know `batch` enough to tell exactly what's going on, but it looks like a poor implementation for two reasons;

1. It's not even running
2. Its way of error handling is repeating indefinitely (might be a feature of `batch`)

**Should I be concerned? If this is legitimate, is there any way for me to allow this to run without changing the default application to open/run `batch` files?**

<sub>** And I do have antivirus software running. It hasn't caught anything related to this.</sub>

Comment: Just to put your mind at ease, others having the same issue: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/v7ibbEPEsBc

Comment: @Papa it looks slightly different. It's regarding the same folder, but their error is that `invisible.vbs` is not running or being blocked.